# Automatically Rewrite URL for Dynamic content in URL : PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

I am trying to get the user details based on their email id so, When Using GET

My URL Looks Like this :

http://localhost/test/profile.php?uid=test@example.com

is there any way that when I send the the Get Request My URL will automatically look like this.

http://localhost/test/profile/test@example.com

> **NOTE** :  The uid value changes if we fetch different email

Comment: first of all passing email_id in URL is not the better practice of code  which is not secure, instead of email_id use `slug` kind of thing

Comment: its not my choice to pass email id. i've been asked to do so.

Comment: Doesn't work --> Add more details, e.g.: error message

Comment: THere are no errors . the .htaccess code doen't work . the URL is same as it is . @Wollmich

Answer (score 0):

There is no automatic way, and rewrite rules won't help you either: they help to map an incoming URL (coming from the browser) into the proper URL needed for your application.

But you are looking for the other way: generate the proper URL that should be shown in the browser's URL bar. This needs to be done in your application by hand - and how to do this is not explainable while you haven't shown your code. A pretty generalized way could look as following:

```
<form action="test/profile/<?php echo $email; ?>">
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^test/profile/(.*)$ /test/profile?uid=$1
```

Comment: I added the above code in .htaccess file but it does not make any difference in the URL

Comment: I tested it with my site and it works. Maybe you missunderstood how this works, its just calling another file, the url in the browser stays the same.
so if you call ceph/profile/pizza the file /ceph/profile.php gets called with uid: pizza

Comment: is there any way that the URL automatically loads in this format . after sending GET Request.

Comment: what do you mean with "the url automatically loads in this format"?

Comment: What I mean to say is that. When I make the get request Then the Next Page URL should not look like this . `http://localhost/test/profile.php?uid=test@example.com`. rather it should automatically look like this `http://localhost/test/profile/test@example.com`

Comment: you cant do that with redirects [more](http://www.htaccessredirect.de/)

Comment: if there is any other alternative you Know. please share it with me.  I am also looking for that. I'll let you know If I found one first

Comment: not in htacces, you would have to change the url in javascript or an othor user-side way